# Cómo hago para ejecutar estos intervalos desde el servidor?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Hola me gustaría que esta función de intervalos que generan combinaciones de letras se ejecutasen desde el servidor de forma cíclica de tal forma que cuando el usuario accede desde el navegador vea la función en el punto exacto al que lo vería otro usuario en el mismo momento y no en el AAAAAA que lo hace ahora... alguna idea? Tal vez PHP.

```js
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo) {
  var $els = $('div[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = 0,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
   $("#layer6_").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
 mostrarEsconder('caso1_', 100),
 mostrarEsconder('caso2_', 500),
  mostrarEsconder('caso3_', 2500),
  mostrarEsconder('caso4_', 12500),
  mostrarEsconder('caso5_', 62500),
  mostrarEsconder('caso6_', 312500);
});
```

```css
#contador{position:absolute; top:100px; border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;}
#daysremaining{font-size:10px; color:blue;display:inline-block;}
#dayslapsed{font-size:10px; color:blue;display:inline-block; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;}
#fluido{background:blue; position:absolute;padding:10px;color:white; font-size:12px;}
.position{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contador">
<div id="daysremaining">
DAYS REMAINING:
</div>
<div id="dayslapsed">
DAYS REMAINING:
</div>
</div>
<div id="fluido">
<div id="caso1_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso1_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso1_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso1_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso1_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso2_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso2_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso2_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso2_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso2_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso3_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso3_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso3_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso3_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso3_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso4_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso4_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso4_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso4_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso4_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso5_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso5_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso5_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso5_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso5_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso6_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso6_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso6_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso6_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso6_5" class="position">E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se podría generar un timestamp en el servidor e insertarlo en el código javascript a modo de inicialización de la siguiente forma:

```js
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo, inicial) {
  var $els = $('div[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = inicial,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.not( ':eq('+i+')' ).hide(); /*Ocultamos los que no sean el inicial */
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
   $("#layer6_").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
    var startdate = "Tue Jun 07 2016 16:13:59 GMT+0200 ",
   today=new Date(),
   timestamp = new Date(startdate) - today;

  mostrarEsconder('caso1_', 100,  Math.floor(timestamp / 100) % 5),
  mostrarEsconder('caso2_', 500, Math.floor(timestamp / 500) % 5),
  mostrarEsconder('caso3_', 2500, Math.floor(timestamp / 2500) % 5),
  mostrarEsconder('caso4_', 12500, Math.floor(timestamp / 12500) % 5),
  mostrarEsconder('caso5_', 62500, Math.floor(timestamp / 62500) % 5),
  mostrarEsconder('caso6_', 312500, Math.floor(timestamp / 312500) % 5);
});
```

```css
#contador{position:absolute; top:100px; border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;}
#daysremaining{font-size:10px; color:blue;display:inline-block;}
#dayslapsed{font-size:10px; color:blue;display:inline-block; 
  padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;}
#fluido{background:blue; position:absolute;padding:10px;color:white; font-size:12px;}
.position{display:inline-block; 
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contador">
<div id="daysremaining">
DAYS REMAINING:
</div>
<div id="dayslapsed">
DAYS REMAINING:
</div>
</div>
<div id="fluido">
<div id="caso1_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso1_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso1_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso1_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso1_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso2_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso2_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso2_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso2_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso2_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso3_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso3_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso3_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso3_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso3_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso4_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso4_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso4_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso4_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso4_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso5_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso5_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso5_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso5_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso5_5" class="position">E</div>
<div id="caso6_1" class="position">A</div>
<div id="caso6_2" class="position">B</div>
<div id="caso6_3" class="position">C</div>
<div id="caso6_4" class="position">D</div>
<div id="caso6_5" class="position">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eres increíble funciona a la perfección; muchas gracias !

Comment: Solo un par de dudas; qué significa que la variable timestamp sea igual a 1464179106428 ? Y lo de % 5 en el cálculo?

Comment: Inicialicé la variable timestamp con un valor (este en concreto era la fecha de ayer a las 12:25:06). Esta variable sería la que habría que inicializar desde el servidor con el timestamp actual para que desde cualquier navegador lo vieran "más o menos" sincronizado.

Comment: El `% 5` es la operación módulo. Es para seleccionar la letra que corresponda según el timestamp. Es 5 porque hay 5 letras (de la A a la E).

Comment: Gracias, he entendido todo a la perfección ! Ahora a ver si me funciona a mí !

Comment: De nada! También tienes que tener en cuenta que la sincronización con el servidor solo se está realizando en el momento de cargar la página. Si las páginas están mucho rato abiertas, tenderá a desincronizarse ya que `setInterval()` no es fiable 100%. Dependiendo de lo que necesites, quizás tendrás que sincronizar cada cierto tiempo con el servidor mediante Ajax como dice Juan Manuel, para obtener un timestamp más actualizado y reiniciar la función.

Comment: Un millón de "upvotes" para ti !

Comment: Hola, disculpa si es tarde para preguntar pero creo que hemos dejado algún fleco suelto... Cuando me he fijado me he dado cuenta de que lo que propones no funciona ya que lo que hace -al menos en intervalos cortos de tiempo- es presentar la serie iniciada pero SIEMPRE en el mismo punto por lo que deduzco que no está llevando el tiempo correctamente... y si lo vinculase con una cuenta atrás desde una fecha en php?

Comment: Estoy esbozando una posible solución haciendo una resta desde la fecha de inicio hasta la fecha de carga de la web para obtener en milisegundos el tiempo y calcular desde qué punto tiene que iniciarse la secuencia, publicaré una pregunta brevemente.

Comment: No se si entiendo bien tu duda... la variable `timestamp` hay que inicializarla desde el lado del servidor (por ejemplo con el código PHP que te indicaba en el comentario del código). Si se usa el código tal cual, siempre empezará la serie por el mismo punto porque la variable timestamp está fijada.

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido, el código lo dejo tal cual está, el timestamp corresponde con la fecha de inicio de la secuencia, añado <?php round(microtime(true) * 1000); ?>  antes del script obtengo así los milisegundos del momento actual desde el momento de inicio haciendo que se actualize el timestamp y la función me muestre las letras que mostrarían en ese momento si nunca saliese de la página, es así?

Comment: No sería más sencillo fijar una fecha de inicio, restarle el momento actual y utilizar eso como variable para mostrar lo que corresponda al momento de cargar la página? Podría actualizarse también peródicamente.

Comment: La fecha de inicio (el timestamp 0) es el 1 de enero de 1970, creo que no necesitas complicarlo más a no ser que quieras fijar otra fecha de inicio concreta

Comment: Claro gparis, lo que quiero es hacer que empiece imaginemos el 15 de julio de 2016 de ahí lo de la resta, a ver lo que voy sacando ! Y muchas gracias por responderme :)

Comment: He hecho una modificación pero no parece funcionar bien del todo, ahora en lugar de ser siempre en el mismo sitio parece aleatorio.

Comment: Vale, estaba mal la operación, es new date - fecha inicial gracias !

Answer (score 0):

cada proceso php que se levanta en el servidor es independiente, lo que puedes hacer es un pequeño servicio en php que entregue via por ejemplo ajax el string que quieres, pero ese servicio que también se va a levantar independientemente debe mantener su estado en algún archivo temporal o en una base de datos.
Tal vez con memoria comártida, pero no es trivial trabajar con eso http://php.net/manual/es/book.shmop.php

Comment: Hola Juan, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, entiendo lo que quieres decir pero me parece una solución más complicada que la de @gparis ... qué ventajas tiene sobre ésta?

Comment: Me imagino que debería usar shmop_open para crear el segmento de memoria compartida en el servidor; darle un nombre (key), utilizar el flag "a" para hacerlo solo en lectura - ya que sólo quiero que se cargue en el navegador las letras visibles en ese preciso instante y que desde ahí continúe la secuencia - en cuanto al tamaño y al tipo l averdad es que no entiendo.